# Is SendGrid integration via Google Cloud Launcher per project or per account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sendgrid, billing

I set up SendGrid integration using the Google Cloud Launcher. I was assuming that I had to set it up per project, but it seems to be activated for all the projects I have billing access to.

If it's per account, how can I have billing for sendgrid separated per project?

I ask this because we build projects for clients, and then once we complete the project and turn it over, we change the billing account for that project to be handled by the client.